# Is this inheritance valid for algebraic extensions?

Tags: extension-field

Let $E/F$ be an algebraic extension.

Let $\sigma:F\to E$ be a homomorphism in the category of fields.

> Can it be shown that the extension $E/\sigma(F)$ is also algebraic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example, based somehow on Qiaochu’s: Take any field $k$, and let $E=F=k(t_1,t_2,t_3,\cdots)$, a purely transcendental extension of $k$ of countable transcendence degree. Then we can set $\sigma:F\to E$ by $\sigma(t_i)=t_{i+1}$, but identity on $k$. Then $E$ is a transcendental extension of $\sigma(F)$, with transcendence basis $\{t_1\}$.

I suppose that the question to ask is what the situation may be if $\sigma$ is a $k$-morphism when $E$ and $F$ are finitely generated fields over $k$.

Comment: Thank you. A nice evidence that - at least when it concerns mathematics - you are not "depleted of merit" at all!

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, take $E = F = \mathbb{C}$. I claim there are maps $\sigma : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ making $\mathbb{C}$ a non-algebraic extension of itself. This is because every algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and the same cardinality as $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, and in particular the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ has these properties.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for a "yes", but the fact that I did not encounter anything about it made me suspect that it would be a "no" :-(. I will need some time to digest your answer.

Comment: I have chosen to accept the answer of @Lubin. This because he produced a cut and dried counterexample.